# padovan series in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I try to write a code which lists the numbers according o padovan series. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence) In the program I will write N as the size and it will list all them from 0 to N. It also will sum the even and odd numbers separately. It will also give an error message if N is 0. When I write the code I get various errors. I will be very happy if you help.

```
public static void main( String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

    int i, j, n, odd, even, x;      
    odd = 0;
    even = 0;   

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of integers that will be generated ( n ) :");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    ArrayList<Integer> padovan = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    padovan.add[1];
    padovan.add[1];
    padovan.add[1];

    if(n != 0)
    {
        for(i = 3; i <= n - 1; i++)
        {

            padovan.add[i, [padovan.get[i - 2] + padovan.get[i - 3]]];

        }   

        for(j = 0; j <= n - 1; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Index : " + j + " Value : " + padovan.get[j]);

            x = padovan.get[j] % 2;

            if (x == 1)
            {
                odd = odd + padovan.get[j];
            }
            else
            even = even + padovan.get(j);

        }
        System.out.println("Sum of odd numbers in the list : " + odd);  
        System.out.println("Sum of even numbers in the list : " + even);    
    }
    else
    System.out.println("No number is generated!");

}
```

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: many different types of error bu mostly "not a statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all arraylist methods you wrote [ ] instead of ( ). When you change all the [ ]'s to ( ) the program should work. Be careful with parenthesizes in methods.